# Return empty string instead of System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have an application which is made up of many different control types, each of which can, optionally, be linked with a parameter object.

These are then saved in an XML file for reloading later. To link the control to the parameter, where specified, the control stores the parameters ID. This is then searched for during loading and re-linked.

However as this is optional, if the parameter is not specified I get a NullReferenceException when trying to access the ID which is understandable. I could resolve this by putting a check around the line in question. However i would have to do this for many different control types and more than just one reference as show in this basic example.

So my question is, is there an elegant way to somehow allow this call to just return an empty string instead of this exception?

```cs
public class Parameter
{
  public string ID;
}

public class LabelCtrl
{
  public string Name;
  public Parameter LinkedParameter;
}

public class XMLManager
{
  public void SaveControl(ControlInstance_LabelCtrl ci)
  {
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ControlInstance_LabelCtrl");
    {
      xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", ci.Name);
      // Elegant way to insert empty string instead of causing NullReferenceException error
      xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", ci.LinkedParameter.ID);
    }
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use Try/Catch? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why catch Exceptions if you can prevent them? @uteist

Comment: I mean, just put it in try/catch and if it's catched, return String.Empty. Or an If x is null then do something block. I still wonder if I'm missing something @PatrickHofman

Comment: Yes, exception handling is expensive. If you can prevent an exception from happening, you should do that. Exceptions are for exceptions, not for your program flow. @uteist

Comment: I think this would really bloat the code as it would need to be kept in line, to ensure the continuity of the XML file. and would be in many places as it is acceptable to have these are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the null propagation operator (available from C# 6):

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", ci.Name);
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", ci.LinkedParameter?.ID);
```

Or for pre-C# 6 use:

```
ci.LinkedParameter != null ? ci.LinkedParameter.ID : null;
```

Comment: @PartickHofman I didn't know about this and looks perfect... unfortunatly I am using C#4.5 and cannot upgrade at the moment! :(

Comment: Then use this: `ci.LinkedParameter != null ? ci.LinkedParameter.ID : null;`.

Comment: I had just come to this conclusion myself :) Many thanks for your help, and everyone elses input.

Comment: Correct. An edit of OP which I didn't check too well... @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple test against ci.LinkedParameter.ID as String:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ci.LinkedParameter.ID)) {
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", ci.LinkedParameter.ID);
}
else {
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", String.Empty);
}
```

or use simple try-catch block:

```
try {
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", ci.LinkedParameter.ID);
} 
catch (e) {
    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", String.Empty);
}
```

Those statements apply if you don't want to change behavior of the model, CMIIW.

Comment: It's `LinkedParameter` that is null, not the ID - which wouldn't cause a NullReferenceException anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator if you don't use C# 6:

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString("LinkedParameter", (ci.LinkedParameter != null) ? ci.LinkedParameter.ID : "");
```

It's an if/else but more compact and more elegant if you have lots of lines like this.